# Custom Html for Orchard content type

Tags: c#, orchardcms

How can I use custom HTML style for my custom content type that I've created from the admin dashboard?

Specifically, I've created content type, and implemented it into a list, so it looks like blog posts list but it isn't.

I would like for an example, remove this "Classifields" title, and i would like to reorganize the layout for the date of creation and this comment indicator that you can see in the picture.

[image: Picture 1]

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options for this. The most (easy) used way is use placement.info, at least for the title:

```
<Placement>
    <Match ContentType="MyCustomContentType">
        <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
    </Match>
</Placement>
```

'Reorganize Layout' im not sure what you mean by that, but you can always take over the rendering by defining an alternate. Enable the 'Shape Tracing' module, then click the part you want to reorganize. Checkout the Alternates under Shape and choose which you want to override. Then you can fully customize that part.

The alternate for this is probably:

Content-MyCustomContentType.Summary.cshtml